# Using Multiple Variables to Create a Single Data Matrix in ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I am trying to set up a label template for a Zebra printer that has 4 variables containing different pieces of information, `FN1`, `FN2`, `FN3`, and `FN4`. These 4 variables are printed to text and barcode fields on the label, however I also want to concatenate them together to create a single data matrix containing the data in all 4 variables.

I have tried inserting line breaks using `\&` as suggested on page 144 of [the documentation](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) but this does not seem to have any effect. The code for the field data I'm trying to use is shown below.

`^FH\^FN1\&^FN2\&^FN3\&^FN4^FS`

Only the content of the last variable in the list (`FN4`, in that case) is encoded into the data matrix, the rest are ignored. I suspect I'm missing something fairly straightforward, but have not been able to find any articles relating to this exact problem.

Comment: There is a missing ^ character before FN2. Also why T before FN3 ?

Comment: Noted, those were proofreading errors. I've fixed the question, and double-checked my template on my printer, unfortunately it's not fixed the problem. FN4 is still the only value represented in the data matrix

Comment: `^FN` is essentially a substitute for `^FD`.  You only get one per command.

Comment: Ok, is there another approach to achieving this I can look into that you're aware of? This seems like it should definitely be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to concatenate multiple variables into a single command in ZPL.  The sending software will need to create a single variable that contains all of the values and delimiters (line breaks).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll look into what I can do on the scanner and if I find an appropriate solution to post as an answer for this question, I'll do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this kind of solution, I have received confirmation from Zebra that this is unfortunately not currently (as at 01/02/2023) possible in ZPL. You should be able to implement it with ZBI, but this is quite a different approach and requires compatible hardware.